# Why isn't the .post jquery function working in my code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried a jquery function using jQuery and it's not working

It's pretty weird. I put some alerts in the js file, but when I click on the button (with id="gettotalnutrients"), none of the alerts from the js file happen.

this is where I grab the data for the js file (and display the data):

```
        <div id="feedback"></div>
    <br />
    <form id="form_date_nutrient_getter" action="account-overview.php" method="POST">
    Select a start date: <input id="datestart" type="text" name="beginday_calendar"><br />
    Select a end date: <input id="dateend" type="text" name="endday_calendar"><br />
                    <input type="button" id="gettotalnutrients" value="Get the total nutrients" ><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </form>
    </div>
```

---

js file:

```
$('#gettotalnutrients').click(function(){
           alert('test');
           var datestart = $('#datestart').val();
           alert(datestart);
           var dateend = $('#dateend').val();
           alert(dateend);
           $.post('getTotalNutrients.php',(beginday_calendar: datestart, endday_calendar: dateend), function(data){
            $('#feedback').text(data);
                });
                                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap your click() function in $(document).ready() or something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gettotalnutrients').click(function(){
    // the rest of your code goes here
  });
});
```

Also, are you seeing any errors in the js console?

Comment: thanks kclair - I wrapped it with the document.ready and it still didn't work or have the alerts come up.

I checked the js console and it said that there was a missing parentheses in column 61 for this line: 

  $.post('getTotalNutrients.php',(beginday_calendar: datestart, endday_calendar: dateend), function(data){
            $('#feedback').html(data);
                });

Answer (score 1):

Did you try chnaging the brackets to {

```
  $(function(){
      $('#gettotalnutrients').click(function(){
       //remaining code  

         $.post('getTotalNutrients.php',{ beginday_calendar: datestart, endday_calendar: dateend}, function(data){
                $('#feedback').text(data);
              });

           });            
    });
```